# Is it possible to add an object refernce User Defined Variable in JMeter?

Tags: jmeter

I can see that User Defined Variables can populate vars with string values only. Is there a way to populate an object reference User Defined Variable in User Defined Variables element.

I have tried as UDV values something like `${__groovy(new java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentHashMap())}`. But this way leads to some string retrieved from the variable later.
I have even tried to use side effects of User Defined Variables groovy scripts like `${__groovy(vars.putObject("key", new java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentHashMap(); "assigned")}`. But this one leads to some JMeter compilation error while being syntactically OK groovy script in my opinion.
I have tried using scripting pre-processors put on top of the test plan like one of SO answers suggested but they work before each sampler in the tree and thus do not what is intended do.

I still can't find a way to initialize an object reference variable in JMeter at the test plan initialization phase hijacking the thread initializing UDVs.

I know of possibilities to populate vars with `putObject(<key>, <reference value>)` from within scripting elements like JSR223/BeanShell/some others sampler/pre-processors etc.
But I want to populate the vars for all my thread groups at the initialization of the test plan in order to avoid using props imposing synchronized lock penalty on each put/get call. And there is no possibility to add a sampler at the top of the test plan.

**EDIT** after accepting correct answer by Dmitri T (for those who want to know the answer right away in more clear form):

`${__groovy(vars.putObject("<key>"\, new HashMap()); "virtually anything")}`

is correct (while indirect) way to populate an object reference variable in UDV test plan element.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> while being syntactically OK groovy script in my opinion.

it's only your opinion, look at [jmeter.log file](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#logging) and you will see interpretation error there

As per [JMeter Documentation](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html):

> If a function parameter contains a comma, **then be sure to escape this with "`\`"**, otherwise JMeter will treat it as a parameter delimiter. For example:
>
> ```
> ${__time(EEE\, d MMM yyyy)}
> ```

the correct syntax would be something like:

```
${__groovy(vars.putObject('key'\,new java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentHashMap()),)}
```

Demo:

[image]

More information: [Apache JMeter Functions - An Introduction](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/apache-jmeter-functions-introduction)

Comment: I understand you second quote lost \ between the double quotes when pasted. Works fine with \ . Thanks!

Comment: It's interesting that either a comma or semi-colon works fine after vars.putObject closing round bracket.